# Creating weekly/monthly/daily leader board

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, cron

I am looking to create a leader board for a online multiplayer game. Leader board will be calculated on weekly/monthly/daily based on the number of games they have played in the given time period.

I want to know what can be the best approach for same, the only solution seems to be writing cron jobs. Is there any other way to do the same or should I go cron jobs.

I am using RoR and Node.js for developing the app. https://github.com/javan/whenever seems to be a good pick for this scenario.

Comment: I use the `whenever` gem for scheduled jobs (daily, weekly and monthly). It works great, if your host is linux-based.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like try any other things than cron job, try [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). Hope this might be useful.